# Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\example\echo.php on line 8 Array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
<?php
    $products = array();    
    $products[101] = array(
        "name" => "Logo Shirt, Red",
        "price" => 18,
        "img" => "img/shirts/shirts-101.jpg"
);
    echo $products;
?>
```

I am trying to run this php file and it keeps giving me this error - 
 **Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\example\echo.php on line 8 Array.**

All i want to do is echo out each and every element inside the array.
I've also tried

```
<?php
    $products = array();    
    $products[101] = array(
        "name" => "Logo Shirt, Red",
        "price" => 18,
        "img" => "img/shirts/shirts-101.jpg"
    );
    foreach($products as $product){
        echo $product;
    }
?>
```

EDIT1: okay guys what if there are multiple similar arrays like 
    $product[101]
    $product[102]
    $product[103]
    $product[104]
    .
    .
    .
    $product[n]

What then?

Comment: `foreach($products[101] as $product)` - [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: @Fred -ii- yep, i tried googling it and didn't found anything useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you `echo` an array, it will either give you an error or just output "Array".

In your second example, `$products[101]` is *also* an array.

So you can do this:

```
foreach($products as $product){
    foreach($product as $key => $val){
        echo "$key: $val";
    }
}
```

Or use `print_r` to output the data in an array:

```
foreach($products as $product){
    print_r($product);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to print the $products[101] just do the foreach but do

```
$products[101] as $product
```

instead

Answer (score 0):

simply just use:

`print_r($products)` or

`var_dump($products)`

That should do it for you...cheers

Answer (score 0):

print_r ($products);
Use print_r method to print arrays.