# array to string conversion in php and displaying in table

Tags: php, regex, parsing

I have a text file, I am parsing it using a regex and saving in the table, is shows me Notice: Array to string conversion in /opt/lampp/htdocs/parsermine/index.php on

the regex is

```
preg_match_all('/([0-9]{1,3}.){3}[0-9]{1,3}/', $line, $matches); var_dump($matches[0]);
```

and dump is

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(11) "192.168.1.2" } 
array(1) { [0]=> string(11) "192.168.1.2" } 
array(1) { [0]=> string(11) "192.168.1.2" } 
array(1) { [0]=> string(11) "192.168.1.2" }
```

help me to sort out the problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\example\echo.php on line 8 Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34208064/notice-array-to-string-conversion-in-c-xampp-htdocs-example-echo-php-on-line-8)

Comment: I didn't have that notice, I'm using PHP 7. Are you sure this is what triggered the notice, and why a notice should be a problem? just saying

Comment: Which line of `index.php` does the error message point to? What is on that line? What is `$line`? Is it a string or an array?

Comment: I can't even replicate the problem. If $line is an array you get a fatal warning saying preg_match needs two strings one array is given. If the $line is a string then all works as it's supposed to. And I don't understand the dump. It returns four arrays like that. I can't make that happen either. There must be more code that is causing the problem that we don't see.

Comment: Actually I want to display the dump in a column of html table, and it displays the notice over there.
 <td><?php print $matches[0]" <br> "."\n";?></td>

Comment: I was able to do it using 
$matches[0][0] = $new_array[0][0];
echo $new_array[0][0];